# Как правильно установить первую букву в верхнем регистре в слове

Tags: javascript

Есть олимпиадная задача, суть которой получить логин из prompt в переменную userInput и сравнить ее с массивом логинов logins.

Так как получаемый логин может быть в любом регистре, необходимо его привести в следующий Формат, где первая буква заглавная, а последующие строчные, и после уже сравнивать.

Учитывая иммутабельность строк в js рекомендовано переводить их в массивы и после проводить манипуляции с ними.
Но можно же изменить регистр символов и без массива, поэтому интересует какой из приведенных ниже примеров более корректный или же они равнозначны.

```js
let str1 = 'Mango'; // строка в массиве
let str2 = 'MANGO'; // получаемая строка; регистр всех символов может быт разным

console.log('str1:', str1);
console.log('str2:', str2);

// вариант 1
str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
str2 = str2[0].toUpperCase().concat(str2.slice(1));
// или 
//str2 = str2[0].toUpperCase() + str2.slice(1);

// вариант 2
const arr = str2.split('');
arr[0] = arr[0].toUpperCase();
str2 = arr.join('');

console.log(`после преобразования str1: ${str1}, str2: ${str2}`)
console.log('str1 === str2:', str1 === str2);
```

Comment: *Учитывая иммутабельность строк в js рекомендовано переводить их в массивы и после проводить манипуляции с ними.* Тебе ж только сравнить! Ну и пусть сравнивается копия - тебе какая печаль-то? всё равно сравнил да забыл - задачи использовать приведённую к формату строку вроде как не ставится.

Comment: Просто ради интереса: а зачем первую букву делать заглавной, если можно все перевести в нижний регистр?

Comment: ) Такой пример разбирали в видео, которое нашел. Да и привести одну строку к формату, мне кажется, будет меньше строк) + Новички всегда заморачиваются, чтобы перепробовать разные варианты..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str = "dasfasdAsdasaSASasd";
str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: А остальные привести к нижнему регистру?

Comment: Да, только после slice надо ещё toLowerCase, если делать по условию

Comment: @AlexDevTime исправился (прочитал только заголовок вопроса )

Comment: А как насчет варианта с метдом concat? str = str[0].toUpperCase().concat(str.slice(1).toLowerCase()); Или он менее читабельный?